# Deleting files in temporary directory generated by laravel-snappy

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-snappy

We are using this library [laravel-snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) to generate PDFs in the queue.

The library is designed to delete all the tmp files after execution of the script. This is due to the following code in `Knp\Snappy\AbstractGenerator` class :

```
public function __destruct()
{
    $this->removeTemporaryFiles();
}
```

Reference - https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/blob/master/src/Knp/Snappy/AbstractGenerator.php#L57

As we are using this inside a queue job and in Laravel once the `queue:work` command has started, it will continue to run until it is manually stopped or you close your terminal.

So to clean the tmp files I have to restart the queue worker everytime.

Is there any alternative to this?

Note - The instance of class `Knp\Snappy\AbstractGenerator` inside the wrapper of laravel-snappy is `protected`. So I can't call its methods directly.

Reference - https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/blob/master/src/PdfWrapper.php#L20

Comment: there is a loop in this function check php configuration may be issue of max execution time try small amount of files deletion second thing check your folder permission.

Comment: you want that queue worker should start automatically everyday and delete your temp files ? what you actually want please specify clearly even you can change the location of temp folder using setTemporaryFolder why you are worrying  for this little thing.

Answer (score 0):

*Reff:-* [Read this doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues)

Supervisor Configuration

Supervisor is a process monitor for the Linux operating system, and will automatically restart your queue:listen or queue:work commands if they fail. To install Supervisor on Ubuntu, you may use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

Supervisor configuration files are typically stored in the /etc/supervisor/conf.d directory. Within this directory, you may create any number of configuration files that instruct supervisor how your processes should be monitored. For example, let's create a laravel-worker.conf file that starts and monitors a queue:work process:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log
```

In this example, the numprocs directive will instruct Supervisor to run 8 queue:work processes and monitor all of them, automatically restarting them if they fail. Of course, you should change the queue:work sqs portion of the command directive to reflect your chosen queue driver.

Once the configuration file has been created, you may update the Supervisor configuration and start the processes using the following commands:

```
sudo supervisorctl reread

sudo supervisorctl update

sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*
```

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't get the question. I will rephrase it again and give more details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the library, but from what I understand, there is a Generator class that you use to generate the PDFs.

Once this class is released, it deletes all tmp files, because the destructor is called.

There is a reference to an implementation of

```
Knp\Snappy\AbstractGenerator
```

like `$generator = new SomeConcreteGenerator();`

which seems to be held by the wrapper, so you cannot set it to null.

You probably get the wrapper, that holds the concrete generator via

```
$pdf = App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');
```

So you could release the wrapper via `$pdf = null` and then make a new one. You'd have to do this after like 1000 Pdfs are created.

The problem with this approach is, that the service is bound to the DIC as a singleton via `$this->app->singleton(...)`. [See source code](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/blob/master/src/ServiceProvider.php).

So it keeps the reference that we want to release.

Give it a try and do a regular binding by modifying their source code to `$this->app->bind(...)` instead of `$this->app->singleton(...)`.

[See here on binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container).

(You should not call `__destruct()` as you basically destruct an object that is owned by the DIC.)

Comment: `$pdf = null` didn't help but when I do something like `$pdf->__destruct()` then it calls the destruct of class `Knp\Snappy\AbstractGenerator` and deletes all the tmp file. I am not 100% convinced with this solution so I will give a PR to the library with some alternatives. Let me know if you have any other idea.

Comment: Yes, you are right on `__destruct()` thing. Will avoid to use it.

Comment: Have you tried regular binding instead of singleton?